# Spring Boot In Memory DB HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hsqldb

I am trying to create a table and trying to insert some dummy values. Here is the SQL

```
CREATE TABLE  IF not exists some_mapping_table (
   access_code integer NOT NULL,
   email_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 100, 'me@you.com');
INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 110, 'me@you.com');
INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 120, 'me@you.com');
INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 130, 'me@you.com');
INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 140, 'me@you.com');
INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 150, 'me@you.com');
INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 160, 'me@you.com');
INSERT INTO some_mapping_table  (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 170, 'me@you.com');
```

The exception while starting the boot application I get is,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #15 of URL [file:/Users/vprasanna/Development/Workspace/apple/apple-workplace-dashboard/out/production/resources/data.sql]: INSERT INTO some_mapping_table (access_code, email_id) VALUES ( 100, 'me@you.com'); nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
...common frames omitted

Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
... common frames omitted

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
```

This is failing when I try to start the application. I am using `org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.5.0` for runtime. Need help in finding some solution.

I have this in the `data.sql`

Comment: I dom't see 15 statements here.

Comment: are you sure email_id should be a String? sounds more like a foreign key id. Could you check if the table already exists with different types - Drop all tables and start fresh.

Comment: Yes it is a foreign key to another table. I have user table that has user details, access table that has the role names. and this is the mapping table that has just the permissions that the user has. I have not added entire SQL file.

Comment: This is similar to the example in this link, http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/1010__JPA_ManyToMany_Join_Table.htm

Comment: You need to add the entire SQL file for the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements. It looks like you have already created the some_mapping_table with different column types. Also try removing IF NOT EXISTS.

Comment: That help me fredt. I always assumed that when I use in-memory db the db is created every time I restart.  When we keep changing the structure, I think it will drop and start afresh time. That does not seam to be the case. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_mapping_table CASCADE` did the trick.